# Globally available url param in angular router

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

I am trying to build a map-centric app similar to google maps. So there is mainly a map, and depending on the url route, a component is loaded inside a small side-panel.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home/:coordinates', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'dashboard/:coordinates', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'utils/:coordinates', component: UtilsDemo},
];
```

What I would like to achieve is similar to google maps:

/home/@54.072,-2.899 --> loads the `HomeComponent` and navigates to the coordinates 54.072,-2.899

/dashboard/@53.123,2.345--> loads the `DashboardComponent` and navigates to the coordinates 54.123,2.345

However, the `:coordinates` param shouldn't be local to the component, but somehow globally. Otherwise I have to do the navigation part inside each and every component.

In other words: If I do:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   console.log(params['coordinates']);
});
```

from within `AppComponent`, the param is not defined. It only works inside each particular component.

Is there any way to achieve this in Angular5?

Comment: Can you post your solution here done via query params? How are you updating params from the component is the user pans the Map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a `Route Resolver` is an option for you. It is usually used for fetching data from a server before navigating to a route but you could just put your navigation logic in there.

1. Create a service `NavigationResolver` for your navigation logic
2. The service implements the [Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) interface.
3. Within the `resolve` method, you extract the params and start the navigation logic

   ```
   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Crisis> {
     let coordinates = route.paramMap.get('coordinates');

     // This is where your navigation happens
     return this.navigateTo(coordinates)
   }
   ```
4. You add the `NavigationResolver` to all routes that should handle the params:

   ```
   {
     path: 'home/:coordinates',
     component: HomeComponent,
     resolve: {
       navigationResult: NavigationResolver
     }
   },
   ```
5. If necessary, you can access the resolved navigation data from within your components via

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
     this.route.data
       .subscribe((data: { navigationResult: NavigationResult }) => {
         this.navigation = data.navigationResult;
       });
   }
   ```

Read more about `Route Resolvers` in the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data).

Comment: This looks very promising! Thank you, I'll try it out asap!

Comment: It does indeed work perfectly! One thing that I forgot to mention, was that I also need to update the coordinates in the URL, whenever the user changes the visible extent/center point of the map, for example in the AppComponent which is notified by the map in such events. Since I cannot find out the current route (home, dashboard etc.) from there, I will probably have to remember it and do the whole angular navigation from within the NavigationResolver service too right?

Comment: Now that I think about it, maybe it makes more sense to use query params instead of route params after all. They are accessible globally from any component. Have a look here: https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters

Comment: How did you change url params if user changes the center point of the map?

Comment: You can just navigate to the new url with the router

Comment: I'm struggling a bit -- should that navigation be done in a route resolver or the main component.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution: Use [query params](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters)

> In the route parameters example, you only dealt with parameters
>   specific to the route, but what if you wanted optional parameters
>   available to all routes? This is where query parameters come into
>   play.

You could subscribe to the `queryParamMap` of the `ActivatedRoute` (e.g. in the `AppComponent`) and do the navigation logic when the param has changed:

```
this.route
      .queryParamMap
      .map(params => params.get('coordinates'))
      .subscribe(coordinates => this.navigationService.navigateTo(coordinates))
```